# Using the CSS transform property with JS - How to use cosine or other angle calculation?

Tags: javascript, css

when I call this in my JS :

`block.style.transform = "rotate(67.5deg) skewX(45deg) scaleY(cos(45deg))";`

Nothing happens on my page, and the console returns an error :

`Error in parsing value for ‘transform’.  Declaration dropped.`

Thos problem is with the last parameter and the cosine.

I tried using Interpolation syntax for the calculation but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to calculate the cos value before you assign the style.

You could use template literals to ` execute the code inline.

```js
elem.style.transform = `rotate(67.5deg) skewX(45deg) scaleY(${Math.cos(45)})`
```

Comment: I did try this method, it returns the Error I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah wait scaleY doesn't use deg it's just an int value. Just remove 'deg'